# Music player that remembers last song and playlist

Tags: music, music-player, playlists, media-manager

I am looking for something similar to winamp.

I have seen other threads but I have tried some solutions and they did not work. I tried Banshee that comes with Ubuntu 11.10 but it does not open last song. 
I tried Rhythmbox with the remember last song plugin however it does not remember the playlist I got the song from so it would start shuffling all my music. 
I tried Amarok and it does the same thing as Banshee except cannot even play my playlist and starts playing all my music.
I tried audacious but importing my playlist .m3u doesnt allow me to select the individual playlists and play them.

I just moved from Windows using winamp and would like a music player that can open playlists .m3u and when I open the application later that it opens the last song and playlist and I can press the play hotkey and music will start playing on startup similar to winamp. I do not care about any additional functionality or user interface.

Answer (score 1):

I’d recommend exaile, or quodlibet with the queue-only plugin.

Both are in the standard Ubuntu repository (check the Software Center).